# Having trouble running and connecting to MongoDB on M1 Pro Monterey 12.0.1

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, macos, macos-monterey

I'm using VS Code, MongoDB Community Server 5.0, node.js backend, and just updated to Monterey 12.0.1. I've followed the instructions to install MongoDB using Mongo instructions [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/). Homebrew installed successfully, MongoDB 5.0 looks like it's installed successfully in the opt/homebrew directory and looks like it's good to go.

There's two problems I'm facing when trying to start and connect to the database from VS Code:

1. MongoDB fails to start when using the `brew services start mongodb-community` (or mongodb-community@5.0) command.

After checking the status using `brew services`, it initially says started with a fresh install/reinstall, but then changes to error immediately. MongoDB was working fine earlier this week, but stopped working randomly and then completely after I updated to 12.0.1. The reason I updated was due to the next issue.

2. Earlier in the week MongoDB started up fine and I was able to connect to the server from VSCode using `npm run dev`, but I began getting the following issue randomly:

   `MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]`

Initially I reinstalled MongoDB and was able to connect again, but then MongoDB began having problems with starting like I mentioned in the first issue. When it was starting, VS Code refused to connect to the database and kept giving the same error.

I haven't made any changes to the backend code/configuration that would have impacted the ability for me to connect from VS Code. When MongoDB was able to start, I could connect to the database through MongoDB Compass just fine, but VS Code still refused to connect. We did some research and tried to change the mongoose.connect from localhost to localhost:27017, tried starting with a fresh repo, reinstalling MongoDB a few times, but with no luck.

We've been trying to resolve this for days now and I'm wondering if this is just an issue with using a new M1 and having to wait for the software to catch up. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone that finds this question - we figured it out after 3 days of trial and error.

We ended up specifying the database folder for the `mongod` command since `brew services` wasn't working using mongo: `alias mongod="mongo --port 27017 --dbpath /opt/homebrew/var/mongodb”`. This solved the first issue and we are able to start the server using `mongod`.

To solve the second issue, I replaced localhost with the specified ip for the mongoose.connect configuration for the app:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/app')
```

For some reason localhost was unable to connect, but using 127.0.0.1:27017 worked.

Comment: right on the point, yo!

Comment: Did the trick for me as well. I would really like to know why the connection string with localhost does not work. In the mongoose docs they say the issue can arise when the local hostname has been changed which I haven't touched. A link to the documentation: [link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/connections.html)

Comment: For me replacing localhost by 127.0.0.1 didn't work. What it ended up doing the trick was adding the parameters directConnection=true&ssl=false to the connection I had in my .env file.

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me**

you just need to go to **/tmp** folder, and remove the **mongodb-27017.sock** file, then you can restart the mongo db in terminal again.

When you remove the **mongodb-27017.sock** file, you need take care about the file owner and permission. If only root user can remove this file, then you need change to root user to remove it.

Comment: I looked at the /tmp folder, but I don't see a mongodb-27017.sock file. I'm new to Macbook so there might be a chance I'm looking in the wrong spot. I went to Finder > Command + Shift + G > /tmp and only see a comp.apple.launch file, MozzileUpdate file, and powerlog folder.

Answer (score 0):

Below command worked for me.

```
mongod --config /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf --fork
```